# Connect job notification alert in reponsys

Tags: oracle, eloqua, responsys

In oracle responsys, I am doing connect job to import a file from the server but in the notification step I observed that, there is an limit to add the emails so I entered the group email id (XYZ@outlook.com) to check whether it triggers or not to the group members but it's not working. So, is there any way we can get the notification ?

Comment: How many people do you want to get the notification? But it should be possible to use a email group email as recipient

Comment: More than 10 people. I tried email as recipient but its not working.